# Can't change folders ownership from root to a user

Tags: command-line, permissions, root, ownership

I tried to change the ownership of two folders with the following commands:

```
chown -v lfs $LFS/tools
chown -v lfs $LFS/sources
```

At the time the commands succeeded as I saw a message saying the change had been done.
Sometime later I checked to see if `lfs` was indeed the owner, with this command:

```
sudo ls -ld /mnt/LFS/sources
```

and got the following answer:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 fev 24 17:39 /mnt/LFS/sources
```

Thinking that I might have to repeat the `chown` command, i did:

```
sudo chown -v lfs $LFS/tools
ownership of '/tools' retained as lfs
```

Now, as far as I understand it, have `chown` telling me that the owner is `lfs` and `ls -ls` saying that the owner is `root`.

The folders are in a external drive disk with a ext4 file system.

Comment: Check the value of your `$LFS` variable. At one point you say `chown ... $LFS/tools` and the error message reports `/tools` in turn, suggesting that `$LFS` is empty there.

Comment: You were right it was empty. I did, again, export LFS=/mnt/lfs and checked if it "stuck".
I tried again, sudo chown -v lfs $LFS/tools, and now I get this message:
chown: cannot access '/mnt/lfs/tools': No such file or directory
failed to change ownership of '/mnt/lfs/tools' to lfs
I did this while located in the /tools folder, so I have no idea why this happening.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just wrote the full path instead of $LFS. Still don't know why I keep loosing the export value, but that is another queation.